# Rendering on an embedded device

Tags: c, graphics, embedded, 2d, rendering

I'm working with a Digilent Uno32 Chipkit and an I/O shield featuring a small 128*32px OLED display. I have a frame rate issue (render time depends on pixels drawn).

My frame is an 512 long byte array, giving a total of 4096 bits (128*32).

My pixel drawing function works in square time (I think), meaning it has to increment a for-loop (which iterates over pixels within columns) nested within another for-loop (which iterates over columns within the screen) to get to the (x,y) pixel position. (Screen is split into 4 horizontal pages.)

I have implemented [Bresenham's line algorithm (for all cases)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) with which I've only drawn 8 lines.

I have a timer (and interrupts) to update the screen every 0.1 seconds, but the screen renders slower that that.

I'm looking for general advice how to get a decent framerate (30-60Hz) regardless of number of pixels drawn (it should be possible on an 80MHz device, Gameboy is lower than that!). Should I reconsider my approach? The line drawing algorithm? Should I look into data structures, hash tables or something similar?

Comment: Are you using a double buffered technique or are you directly writing to the bits from the loop? If I were you I'd memcpy my array to the memory mapped portion of memory that represents the display.

Comment: Thanks, I think your suggestion is right on track! Presently, inside my for loops I only "set" the appropriate bit within the (global) frame array. Only after that do I iterate over the frame array again to render it!

Comment: Performance-critical code on low-end embedded devices are rarely written in a high-level programming language like C, and instead in hand-optimized assembly. There is an [absolute gem of a series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpwlZgQPCpk&list=PLNs6Jw4V4vlvafSs0H3Ww_M5nMm10m0UM) on YouTube about optimizing the Quake engine to run on a 16MHz Atari Falcon030.

Comment: I have an app with a similar OLED, and I make the frame buffer itself have the same bit-layout as the OLED...in fact, I even add extra bytes for command bytes so that my actual rendering function just blasts the whole buffer out to the I2C bus. Then I write my drawing primitives (mostly text in my case) write to that buffer in its native format.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @meowgoesthedog, I'll have a look! I've recently studied some (MIPS) assembly. 

Someone also told me about jaged arrays and making rendering and processing asynchronous to stabilize frame rate...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That sounds brilliant and badass. I will contemplate your actions inside my chamber and come back once I've grasped the implications! I do believe I'm at least laying out the frame buffer array the same way the OLED does, I'll experiment with your suggestions!

Comment: Are you using floating point math for your algorithm?  That will really slow it down.  You need to post your code - the problem will be there.

Comment: Integer math. Can't post due to school. I'm just looking for general advice.

Comment: If you are looking for "general advice" the the question is by definition "too broad".

Comment: The speed of your processor is entirely irrelevant; while you can probably generate the frame buffer very quickly in RAM, the display is not a direct presentation of that frame buffer.  If [this](https://store.digilentinc.com/chipkit-basic-i-o-shield-input-output-expansion-add-on-board-with-oled-display-retired/) is the board you are referring to, the display is on a relatively slow SPI bus, the time taken to update the display will depend on the SPI clock rate used.  That said you must be running it _very_ slow to take as long as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly beginner's mistake relating to the way I set the bits in the frame array. No need to iterate, just address the bits in the frame array directly (with a little bit shifting to shift into the appropriate y position in each column, using a |= to avoid overwriting)!